# How can I play HTML5 videos on YouTube with the latest TorBrowser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

How can I play HTML5 videos on YouTube with the latest TorBrowser?

Even after having activated the HTML5 player on youtube.com/html5, HTML5 videos are not played. Instead, an error message claims that the browser in use does not support the HTML5 video format.

Are there any hints on how I can solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to restart your browser?

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. I can start HTML5 on videos on YouTube without problems. Thus I'm closing this ticket. If you have clarifications, please [edit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/2192/edit) the question and it can be reopened.